# Java Co-variant returns

Tags: java, return-type, covariant

In java why are covariant return types acceptable when non-covariant return types produce a compile time error. Surely if the JVM can handle covariant return types then it can handle noncovariant return types. I presume that when java sees an overridden method with a covariant return it just applies the method that's associated with the calling object. Why can't the same happen with non covariant return types. 
My guess is that it's to do with breaking the terms of the superclass' method contract and of course if this were allowed then the behavior of the sub class (overridden) methods aren't very predictable (since there is no consistency in return type)?

Here's an example (assume that DogFood is a subclass of Food but CatFood is not a subclass of Food):

Animal class

```
public class Animal {

public Food seekFood() {

    return new Food();
}
}
```

Dog class

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

public DogFood seekFood() { //This is OK since its a covariant

    return new DogFood();
}
}
```

Cat class

```
    public class Cat extends Animal {

public CatFood seekFood() { // This won't compile. Catfood is not covariant

    return new CatFood();
}
}
```

Comment: I didn't get your point actually.. It may be a good question but Please explain it with one example.. It would be better for all of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A {
    Ra f(Pa x) { ... }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    Rb f(Pb x) { ... }
}
```

The inheritance rule determines the co-variant/contra-variant behavior:

***A value of type T may only assigned to a variable of type T or parent type.***

A method call implies assigning its actual method arguments (1) to local parameters (2), and assigning the result value (1) to some location (2) to be used.

Now if the compiler meets an A object which actually can be a B, then it follows for `B.f` to be a valid override:

1. Pb may only be valid when it Pa or a parent class (contra-variant);

   Because you `B.f` must be able to receive at least a Pa value.
2. Rb may only be valid when it is Ra or a child class (co-variant);

   Because `B.f` must return something that is assignable to an Ra.

This makes the child class more restrictive, specific.

*On the case at hand, a Cat may return DogFood when DogFood is a child of Food. So any Animal's Food is indeed a Food, even if the Animal is  actual a Cat.*

Answer (score 0):

If two methods have the same signature (method name and argument types) compiler wouldn't be able to decide which method to choose to call to. If two methods have the same name, but different argument types and different return types - they have different signatures and then compiler can choose which one to call.

**UPDATE:**
javac compiles co-variant methods to its base class methods an when you make call to it, base class method delegates call to subclass method. Since they return different types, typecast is not possible. Thanks to [A. Sundararajan's Weblog](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/covariant_return_types_in_java) , that process can be explained very clearly with one code snippet:

```
class CircleFactory extends ShapeFactory {
    public Circle newShape() {
       // your code from the source file
       return new Circle();
    }

    // javac generated method in the .class file
    public Shape newShape() {
       // call the other newShape method here -- invokevirtual newShape:()LCircle;
    } 
}
```

Comment: In my example all three methods have the same signature. However, they all have different return types. In the case of the covariant the compiler doesn't complain and it is able to choose which method to call; it determines which method to call based on the object type. In the Cat example Catfood is not a covariant of Food and hence Cat's seekFood method does not compile. Why is that? I suspect the JVM could treat it like a covariant but if it did then I guess you would then have unpredictable / tightly coupled code?